# Shuffle train,test,validation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a pandas Dataframe and I would like to split the data according to the 'st' column.
Example:

```
| st | s1 | s2 || label |
| -- | -- | -- || ----  |
| 0  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 1  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 2  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 3  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 0  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 1  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 2  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 3  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 0  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 1  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 2  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 3  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 0  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 1  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 2  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 3  | s1 | s2 || label |
```

My training data would be consisting only on st=[0,2] if training is 50% of the data:

```
| st | s1 | s2 || label |
| -- | -- | -- || ----  |
| 0  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 0  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 0  | s1 | s2 || label |
...
| 2  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 2  | s1 | s2 || label |
| 2  | s1 | s2 || label |
```

Test data st=[1] and Val data st[4].

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this basic [Dataframe row selection](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#)?  E.g., `my_training_data = my_df[my_df["st"].isin([0,2])]` ... but there are lots of ways to select what you want in a Pandas Dataframe.

Comment: I have thousands of files, my 'st' range goes from 0 to 20000, maybe I have first to randomize the values and then select the rows...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Is partitioning a Pandas DataFrame based on column values the question?... Or is there something more?... Or different?

Comment: Yes. I solved the problem following your row selection hint. First from the number of values existing on 'st' I shuffled and divided those values into indexes for training, testing and validation (an array called split). Then: train = d[d["structure"].isin(["%.0f" % i for i in split[0]])] and the same for test and validation.